# How to assign a new value to a global variable in GML

Tags: game-maker, random

I have a variable called `global.goldchance = irandom(99);`. I use it to get a random number from 0 to 99. However, I need to be able to run it again so that the variable gets a new random number. Writing `var goldchance = irandom(99);` doesn't work as that will destroy the variable afterward. Simply writing the global variable again in a new location won't work as that is just stating it and doing nothing with it. How do I do this?

Comment: Share your code and try to state what exactly you are trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Presumably you tried writing `global.goldchance = irandom(99);` a second time when you want to generate a new random number to store in it? What went wrong when you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the value of a GLOBAL variable you would just assign it a new value the same you would with a normal variable. You would just insert:

```
    global.goldchance = value;
```

"Simply writing the global variable again in a new location won't work as that is just stating it and doing nothing with it." -- Yes it will, as long as you're assigning a value to it.

Comment: Didn't realize this was posted two years ago. I assume you've already found the answer at this point.